# How do I write a VB.Net method to filter a URLs?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, content-management-system

I am attempting to write a method using VB.NET that will allow me to read in a URL and compare it to a list. If it is one of the URLs on the list then Bing Tracking conversion will be applied. 
At the moment I can only think do write it as a comaparative method, comapring the current URL with the ones that require tracking (a list). This, however, sems a little long winded. 
Each page may have a different querystring value/page id, there for its fundamental to get exactly the right page for the tracking to be applied to.
Any Ideas?

Sorry I really am a novice when developing functions in VB.Net
If I were to use th Contains() function then I would imagine that it would look a little something like this:

```
Private sub URL_filter (ByVal thisPage As ContentPage, brandMessage? As   Boolean) As String
    Dim url_1 As String = "/future-contact thanks.aspx"
    Dim url_2 As String = "/find-enquiry thanks.aspx?did=38"                                                          
    Dim url_3 As String = "/find-enquiry-thanks.aspx?did=90"
    Dim url_4 As String = "/find-enquiry-thanks.aspx?did=62"    
    Dim result as String

    result = CStr (url_1.Contains(current_URL))

    txtResult.Text = result 
End Sub
```

If I were to use this then what type of loop would I have to run to check all the URLs that are in my list against the current_URL? Also where would I define the current_URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Contains()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) function to check if the list contains the given value. You could also implement a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), but it is probably overkill for your purposes. Here is an example:

```
Dim UrlList As New List(Of String)
UrlList.Add("www.example2.net") 'Just showing adding urls to the list
UrlList.Add("www.example3.co.uk")
UrlList.Add("www.exampletest.com")

Dim UrlToCheck As String = "www.exampletest.com" 'This is just an example url to check

Dim result As Boolean = UrlList.Contains(UrlToCheck) 'The result of whether it was found
```

Make sure to add these imports `Imports System` and `Imports System.Collections.Generic`

**Disclaimer: I have no experience with VB.NET**

Comment: I am a novice at VB.NET so I am unsure of exactly how this would work.

Comment: I have posted above roughly how I would implement the Contains() function. If I were to use this then what type of loop would I have to run to check all the URLs that are in my list against the current_URL? Also where would I define the current_URL?

Comment: @CodingNovice I'll try to provide a working code example, but it will probably take me a day or two (Since I don't really know VB.NET).